# How to unit test a React component that renders after fetch has finished?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, fetch-api, jest-fetch-mock

I'm a Jest/React beginner. In jest's `it` I need to wait until all promises have executed before actually checking.

My code is similar to this:

```js
export class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { /* Some state */ };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(some_url)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => this.setState(some_state);
    }

    render() {
        // Do some rendering based on the state
    }
}
```

When the component is mounted, `render()` runs twice: once after the constructor runs, and once after `fetch()` (in `componentDidMount()`) finishes and the chained promises finish executing).

My testing code is similar to this:

```js
describe('MyComponent', () => {

    fetchMock.get('*', some_response);

    it('renders something', () => {
        let wrapper = mount(<MyComponent />);
        expect(wrapper.find(...)).to.have.something();
    };
}
```

Whatever I return from `it`, it runs after the first time `render()` executes but before the second time. If, for example, I return `fetchMock.flush().then(() => expect(...))`, the returned promise executes before the second call to `render()` (I believe I can understand why).

How can I wait until the second time `render()` is called before running `expect()`?

Comment: It sounds to me like you're trying to test too many things in one test. What you want to test is that your fetch function is called when the component mounts, then you have multiple other tests which have the state passed in to them explicitly and you can check that the component is rendered properly.

Comment: @MattWatson If I check (1) that the fetch function is called and (2) that passing the state renders properly, then I have failed to check that (1.5) the state gets set correctly. How would I check that the state has been set correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do what I originally asked. I have no opinion (yet) whether it is good strategy or not (in fact I had to refactor the component immediately afterwards, so this question is no longer relevant to what I'm doing). Anyway, here is the testing code (explanation below):

```js
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import { MyComponent } from 'wherever';
import fetchMock from 'fetch-mock';

let _resolveHoldingPromise = false;

class WrappedMyComponent extends MyComponent {

    render() {
        const result = super.render();
        _resolveHoldingPromise && _resolveHoldingPromise();
        _resolveHoldingPromise = false;
        return result;
    }

    static waitUntilRender() {
        // Create a promise that can be manually resolved
        let _holdingPromise = new Promise(resolve =>
            _resolveHoldingPromise = resolve);

        // Return a promise that will resolve when the component renders
        return Promise.all([_holdingPromise]);
    }
}

describe('MyComponent', () => {

    fetchMock.get('*', 'some_response');

    const onError = () => { throw 'Internal test error'; };

    it('renders MyComponent appropriately', done => {
        let component = <WrappedMyComponent />;
        let wrapper = mount(component);
        WrappedMyComponent.waitUntilRender().then(
            () => {
                expect(wrapper.find('whatever')).toBe('whatever');
                done();
            },
            onError);
    });
});
```

The main idea is that, in the testing code, I subclass the component (if this was Python I'd probably monkey-patch it, which works more or less the same way in this case) so that its `render()` method sends a signal that it executed. The way to send the signal is by manually resolving a promise. When a promise is created, it creates two functions, resolve and reject, which when called terminate the promise. The way to have code outside the promise resolve the promise is by having the promise store a reference to its resolve function in an external variable.

Thanks to fetch-mock author Rhys Evans who kindly explained the manually-resolve-promise trick to me.

Comment: That's bad news man. I hope this isn't the only way to do this!

Answer (score 3):

I'd separate concerns, mainly because is easier to maintain and to test. Instead of declaring the fetch inside the component I'd do it somewhere else, for example in a redux action (if using redux).

Then test individually the fetch and the component, after all this is unit testing.

For async tests you can use the `done` parameter on the test. For example:

```js
describe('Some tests', () => {
  fetchMock.get('*', some_response);

  it('should fetch data', (done) => { // <---- Param
    fetchSomething({ some: 'Params' })
      .then(result => {
        expect(result).toBe({ whatever: 'here' });
        done(); // <--- When you are done
      });
  });
})
```

The you can tests your component by just sending the loaded data in the props.

```js
describe('MyComponent', () => {

  it('renders something', () => {
    const mockResponse = { some: 'data' };
    let wrapper = mount(<MyComponent data={mockResponse}/>);

    expect(wrapper.find(...)).to.have.something();
  });
});
```

When it comes to testing you need to keep it simple, if your component is difficult to test, then there's something wrong with your design ;)

Comment: Is it possible to do it as I originally intended? I am asking in order to get a better grip on async programming.

Comment: Jest is for unit testing, what you are trying to do is not unit testing. That being said, you can manually set the state from your test, for example `wrapper.setState({ some_state })` then `expect(wrapper.find(...)).to.have.something();`. To tests the fetch... there are not many options here other than take it away from the component ;)

Answer (score 1):

I've had some success with this, as it doesn't require wrapping or modifying components.  It is however assuming there's only one `fetch()` in the component, but it can be easily modified if needed.

```
// testhelper.js

class testhelper
{
    static async waitUntil(fnWait) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let count = 0;
            function check() {
                if (++count > 20) {
                    reject(new TypeError('Timeout waiting for fetch call to begin'));
                    return;
                }
                if (fnWait()) resolve();
                setTimeout(check, 10);
            }
            check();
        });
    }

    static async waitForFetch(fetchMock)
    {
        // Wait until at least one fetch() call has started.
        await this.waitUntil(() => fetchMock.called());

        // Wait until active fetch calls have completed.
        await fetchMock.flush();
    }
}

export default testhelper;
```

Then you can use it just before your assertions:

```
import testhelper from './testhelper.js';

it('example', async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent/>);

    // Wait until all fetch() calls have completed
    await testhelper.waitForFetch(fetchMock);

    expect(wrapper.html()).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Comment: That's ugly...is this still the state of the art?

Comment: Not sure as I haven't done much in this area lately, but what about it don't you like?

Comment: The countdown and timer. It would be nice if there was some `processAllPromises` or something. I wound up using `findBy` in the react testing library (I'm testing React): https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries/#findby It still has a timer/timeout and it may be implemented just like this! But at least I don't have to write or see it :-D

Comment: You don't have to use the countdown/timer, it's just there as a backup to avoid a CI/CD server hanging if the promise never completes.  You can search for "flush promises" for details on how to ensure all promises are processed.